# uniqueness of complete space of a given metric space X

Tags: functional-analysis

A given metric space X, consider its smallest complete metric sapce Y which contains X(" smallest" means if Z is an arbitary complete metric space which contains X, then Z contains Y) ("contain"means " there is an injuctive map f:Y->Z, d(f(a),f(b))=d(a,b) )
Question : Is Y is unique up to isomorphism of metric space

Answer (score 0):

$Y$ is called the completion of $X$. And it is indeed unique up to isometry. See [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Completion) to get references.